# MySQL get products with multiple filter values

Tags: mysql

**Question:**
How would I get all products that are `Red` and size `S`?
That would mean that I only get product `2: Product (color:green,red => size:S)`

**Description:**
I'm running into a problem with selecting products from a database that have certain filters applied. Below you will find my tables and see [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb07b/1) for real SQL.

Table `product`:

```
id | title
------------------------------
 1 | Product (color:green => size:S)
 2 | Product (color:green,red => size:S)
 3 | Product (color:red)
```

Table `filter`

```
id | name
------------
 1 | Color
 2 | Size
```

Table `filter_value`

```
id | filter_id | name
---------------------
 1 |         1 | green
 2 |         1 | red
 3 |         2 | S
```

Table `product_filter_value`

```
id | product_id | filter_id | filter_value_id
---------------------------------------------
 1 |          1 |         1 |               1
 2 |          1 |         2 |               3
 3 |          2 |         1 |               1
 4 |          2 |         1 |               2
 5 |          2 |         2 |               3
 6 |          3 |         1 |               2
```

To select all products with the filter value `red`, I run this query:

```
# ALL COLOR RED
SELECT p.*
FROM product p 
  LEFT JOIN product_filter_value pfv ON p.id = pfv.product_id
WHERE (pfv.filter_id IN ('1')) 
  AND (pfv.filter_value_id IN ('2'))
GROUP BY p.id
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

To select all products with the filter value `S`, I run this query:

```
# ALL SIZE S
SELECT p.*
FROM product p 
  LEFT JOIN product_filter_value pfv ON p.id = pfv.product_id
WHERE (pfv.filter_id IN ('2')) 
  AND (pfv.filter_value_id IN ('3'))
GROUP BY p.id
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

But how would I get all products that are `Red` and size `S`?
That would mean that I only get product `2: Product (color:green,red => size:S)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't get the sql fiddle to work, but I thought I'd give this a shot anyway. You might have to have different joins for the different filter types. The join with the table alias pfv1 is for filter1, and pfv2 is for filter 2.

```
SELECT *
FROM product p 
  LEFT JOIN product_filter_value pfv1 ON p.id = pfv1.product_id and pfv1.filter_id = 1
  LEFT JOIN product_filter_value pfv2 ON p.id = pfv2.product_id and pfv2.filter_id = 2
WHERE (pfv1.filter_id IN ('1')) 
  AND (pfv1.filter_value_id IN ('2'))
  and (pfv2.filter_id IN ('2')) 
  AND (pfv2.filter_value_id IN ('3'))
GROUP BY p.id
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

It may be interesting to look at the whole set without the `where` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM product p 
  LEFT JOIN product_filter_value pfv1 ON p.id = pfv1.product_id and pfv1.filter_id = 1
  LEFT JOIN product_filter_value pfv2 ON p.id = pfv2.product_id and pfv2.filter_id = 2

+ ------- + ----------------------------------- + ------- + --------------- + -------------- + -------------------- + ------- + --------------- + -------------- + -------------------- +
| id      | title                               | id      | product_id      | filter_id      | filter_value_id      | id      | product_id      | filter_id      | filter_value_id      |
| 1       | Product (color:green => size:S)     | 1       | 1               | 1              | 1                    | 2       | 1               | 2              | 3                    |
| 2       | Product (color:green,red => size:S) | 3       | 2               | 1              | 1                    | 5       | 2               | 2              | 3                    |
| 2       | Product (color:green,red => size:S) | 4       | 2               | 1              | 2                    | 5       | 2               | 2              | 3                    |
| 3       | Product (color:red)                 | 6       | 3               | 1              | 2                    |         |                 |                |                      |
+ ------- + ----------------------------------- + ------- + --------------- + -------------- + -------------------- + ------- + --------------- + -------------- + -------------------- +
4 rows
```

Product 2 has two records because it has two colors, while product 3 has no values for the last four columns because it has no size attribute.

Comment: SQL Fiddle is indeed broken, doesn't seem to be such a good service. Your first example seems to be working fine. I'm not sure about your second one.  I stil need the filter_value_id to be involved.

Comment: The second example is only intended to give insight into what happens with no filters. Glad the first one works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the 2 elements individually, join them and then filter them (in an easy to read word format)

given (and your sql fiddle doesn't load by the way)

```
/*
drop table if exists product;
create table product(id int ,title varchar(50));
insert into product values
( 1 , 'Product (color:green => size:S)' ),
( 2 , 'Product (color:green,red => size:S)' ),
( 3 , 'Product (color:red)' );

drop table if exists filter;
create Table filter(id int, name varchar(5));
insert into filter values
( 1 , 'Color'),
( 2 , 'Size');

drop table if exists filter_value;
create table filter_value( id int, filter_id int, name varchar(5));
insert into filter_value values
( 1 ,         1 , 'green'),
( 2 ,         1 , 'red'),
( 3 ,         2 , 'S');

drop table if exists product_filter_value;
create Table product_filter_value(id int, product_id int, filter_id int, filter_value_id int);
insert into product_filter_value values
( 1 ,          1 ,         1 ,               1),
( 2 ,          1 ,         2 ,               3),
( 3 ,          2 ,         1 ,               1),
( 4 ,          2 ,         1 ,               2),
( 5 ,          2 ,         2 ,               3),
( 6 ,          3 ,         1 ,               2);
*/
```

The subquery s gets the colors and the subquery t gets the sizes

```
select u.stitle product
from
(
select s.* , t.* from 
(
select p.id sid,p.title stitle,fv.name sfvname,f.name sname
from    product p
join  product_filter_value pfv on pfv.product_id = p.id
join    filter_value  fv on fv.id = pfv.filter_value_id
join  filter f on f.id = fv.filter_id
where f.name = 'color'  
) s
join
(
select p.id tid,p.title ttitle,fv.name tfvname,f.name tfname
from    product p
join  product_filter_value pfv on pfv.product_id = p.id
join    filter_value  fv on fv.id = pfv.filter_value_id
join  filter f on f.id = fv.filter_id
where f.name = 'size'
) t on s.stitle = t.ttitle 
) u
where u.sname = 'color' and u.sfvname = 'red' and u.tfname = 'Size' and u.tfvname = 'S'
```

Comment: SQLfiddle did work, but now it's also broken for me. I always have issues with SQLfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with the simple basis of looking for one thing.
It could be a size, color or anything else your real data has.
The query could be

```
SELECT
      pfv.product_id,
      f.name
   from
      product_filter_value pfv
         join filter_value fv
            ON pfv.filter_value_id = fv.id
              AND fv.name = "what you are looking for"
         JOIN filter f
            ON pfv.filter_id = f.id
```

Now, you could do multiple for each unique joined in the same query.
I will suffix the alias tables for each unique thing being filtered.
You could even add a brand if so applicable by an additional subquery join such as ProdBrand alias

```
SELECT
      p.product_id,
      p.title,
      ProdColor.name as Color,
      ProdSize.name as Size
   from
      Product p
         JOIN ( select 
                      pfv.Product_id,
                      fv.name
                   from 
                      product_filter_value pfv
                         JOIN filter_value fv
                            ON pfv.filter_value_id = fv.id
                           AND fv.name = "red"
                         JOIN filter f
                            ON pfv.filter_id = f.id
                           AND f.name = "Color" ) ProdColor
            ON P.id = ProdColor.Product_ID
         JOIN ( select
                      pfv.Product_id,
                      fv.name
                   from
                      product_filter_value pfv
                        JOIN filter_value fv
                           ON pfv.filter_value_id = fv.id
                             AND fv.name = "S"
                        JOIN filter f
                           ON pfv.filter_id = f.id
                           AND f.name = "Size" ) ProdSize
            ON P.id = ProdSize.Product_ID
```

Now, if you wanted to try for multiple colors or sizes, 
just change each subquery's criteria to something like...

```
 AND INLIST( fv.name, "red", "blue" )  -- example for red OR blue

 AND INLIST( fv.name, "S", "M" )  -- example for Small OR Medium
```

It may be a long query, but looking at each piece individually is quite simple.  Its purpose is the one criteria a color, size, brand, etc. You just are joining on that as part of your overall condition to get products.

I working SQLFiddle from your original schema can be found at [this working sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb07b/3)

Comment: I haven't tested you query. The answer of CGritton seems a lot simpler. I'm not sure on performance. On the other hand, you query works with the filter names instead of the id's.